# How to create a temporary image file with node-webkit?

Tags: image, node.js, node-webkit

I am working on an app with node-webkit to get some data of a TIFF-image. Because of TIFF-images are not supported by webkit, I want to create a temporary PNG version to show it in the app. How could I do this? Is there a way or place for temporary files in node-webkit like App.dataPath? Or should I use another node module [node-temp](https://github.com/bruce/node-temp)?

I'm looking very forward to get your answers soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create temporary image file, try data URL.

```
<h1>You will see an image later</h1>
<img id="img" src="">
<script type="text/javascript">
  //start js code here
  var data_prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET','https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1356417?s=140',true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function(e){
    var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);
    var b64=btoa(raw);
    var dataURL="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+b64;
    img.src = dataURL;
  };
  xhr.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider using the HTML5 File APIs if you are after a pure client-side solution.

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) has you covered.

This is, of course, assuming that you are manipulating the TIFF data in client-side Javascript, and want to write it to a temporary `.png` file.